# Variable from one FOR loop as path for nested FOR loop in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Euro Truck Simulator 2\b\sound` with folders (let's call them folder1, folder2, folder3), and within this folder are files I'd like to list and do stuff.

To do this I wrote a loop that recurse through the folders, and within that loop is another loop that does stuff. I'd like to do this this way, as I'd like to remain the folder1, folder2 etc. structure later on (with `%%~n`).

When I do `for /D %%c in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Euro Truck Simulator 2\b\sound\*") do echo %%c` it lists me the full path to folder1, folder2 etc.

But my problem is I seem to cannot pass the `%%c` variable as path in to another loop, like this:

`for /D %%c in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Euro Truck Simulator 2\b\sound\*") do FOR /R %c% %%G IN (*.bank) DO echo %%G`

return nothing.

`%%c` returns `%G was unexpected at this time.`

`"%c%"` return multiple `The full path of  is too long.` even with `echo %%~nG` and filenames are short

`"%%c"` returns again nothing.

I tried `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and using `!c!` instead of `%c%` but to no avail.

Comment: Were you not intending to use `%%c`, instead of `%c%` or `!c!`? _(and should you not, for safety, be doublequoting it?)_

Comment: `FOR /R` must have a constant for the starting directory. I'd suggest using a subroutine and passing `%%c` (which is completely different from `%c%` and `!c!`) as a parameter or assigning `%%c` to a variable to transport the path to the `for /r` in a subroutine. OR, try `FOR /R %%G IN ("%%c*.bank") DO ...` {I haven't tried this}